# Girl moves to Japan, works in a night club and draws comic

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am looking for the name of a film I saw around 2005, and probably appeared not much earlier.

The main character is a (possibly scandinavian) girl. At her high schools graduation ceremony, she meets a Japanese boy, and spontaneously decides to move to Japan. There she works in a night club. In her free time she draws comics, which are sometimes cut into the live-action film itself. The first part of the film deals with her everyday life, tensions between coworkers. At the middle of the film she says as a narrator that the main character needs a main antagonist, and it is not always clear who the antagonist will be. Then the main antagonist is introduced: A patron of the night club, who likes to dress up the girls, e.g. in bavarian style. One of her coworkers disappears, and there are hints that this guy is connected to this crime. She gets the opportunity to visit him in his house, where it turns out that the missing girl got hurt (possibly with a scissor) during a dispute with two other girls, and is now recovering in his house. She is caught sneaking around, but instead of getting punished she gets an offer to sell her comic as a film script. These final scenes are shown only in her comic pictures. The film then cuts without explanation to a final shot and shows her back home in the garden behind her parents house.

The film might have been a Swedish production. I think the film referred to an actual case of a foreign girl disappearing in Japan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for [Stratosphere Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306097/combined) from 2004.

> Enter a dark, dangerous world where the lines between reality and fantasy are blurred. Angela is 18, a stunning Dutch blonde, a comic illustrator, and bored with life. Eager for adventure, she moves to Tokyo to become a bar hostess for Asian men who like Western women. An innocent in this sexual underworld, she confronts sleazy customers, jealous co-workers and a mystery: the disappearance of a former hostess. As she discovers clues, she sketches them out in comic-strip style, and slowly begins to confuse what she knows with what she draws.

Here's the trailer (in German) **[*Contains Brief Nudity*]**: